# Image.save() And Image.show() Gives Different Result For same Image

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I have a python script which takes a image as input and add some effect to image. After adding effect i am saving image, which gives me 100% correct result. But if do img.show() for the same Image i saved previously it shows me input Image instead of effect added Image. Code is given below

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("1.png").convert('RGBA')
arr = np.array(img)
alpha = arr[:, :, 3]
n = len(alpha)
alpha[:] = np.interp(np.arange(n), [0, 0.55*n, 0.75*n, n], [255, 255, 0, 0])[:,np.newaxis]
img = Image.fromarray(arr, mode='RGBA')
img.save("2.png")
img.show()
```

Comment: I am using the same image viewer but still getting this problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing its because the same image viewer is not used in both times. img.show() uses some different image viewer. Try top open both times with the same image viewer.

Comment: I am using the same image viewer but still getting this problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the weird thing is not that your shown image is identical to the original image, but that your saved image is not. You are setting `img2` from the variable `arr`, which is taken from `img1` and then never changed. You should set `arr[:,:,3] = alpha` before creating `img2`.

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,1],[2,2]])
>>> a
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
>>> b = a[:,1]
>>> b
array([1, 2])
>>> b = [0,3]
>>> a
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
>>> a[:,1] = b
>>> a
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 3]])
```

Comment: Done that. But still getting same Problem.